# Why Apache Artemis Web Console cutting headers?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Artemis web console shorten / cutting the headers? Why? And where can I change this?
ActiveMQ doesn't do this.

```
[
  {
    "messageID": "62277035128",
    "priority": 4,
    "type": 3,
    "StringProperties": {
      "MessageHistory": "<br />04.05.2023 - 15:23:10 Uhr<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Message History<br />---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />Source                           , + 1554 more",
    },
    "DoubleProperties": null,
    "expiration": 0,
    "text": "1;17099
```

Property `MessageHistory` on the end of the line Artemis shows `+ 1554 more`. Why not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis web console truncates headers and body of messages with a size greater of the address setting `management-message-attribute-size-limit`. Default is 256. Use -1 to switch this limit off, i.e.

```
<address-setting match="#">
   <management-message-attribute-size-limit>-1</management-message-attribute-size-limit>
...
```

For further details see [Configuring Addresses and Queues via Address Settings](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html)